# Fatal error: "'Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object'"

Tags: php, pdo

Sorry if it's something very simple and for how much code I pasted. I just don't know how much you need to assess. I've been looking around and all of the fixes on here like global db don't work

```
<?php

namespace thalos_api;
use PDO;

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../database_layer/DBInterface.php');

class APIStatistics
{
private $DB;

public $unique_org_count;
public $total_org_count;
public $unique_acct_count;
public $total_acct_count;
public $total_unique_records;
public $account_refresh_time;
public $org_refresh_time;
public $total_refresh_time;
public $current_refresh_cycle;
public $total_users;
public $total_hits;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->DB = new DBInterface();
    $this->DB->Connect();

    $this->unique_org_count = $this->GetSingleCount('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM organizations_rsi');
    $this->total_org_count = $this->GetSingleCount('SELECT COUNT(sid) FROM organizations_rsi_info') + $this->unique_org_count;

    $this->unique_acct_count = $this->GetSingleCount('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM accounts_rsi');
    $this->total_acct_count = $this->GetSingleCount('SELECT COUNT(handle) FROM accounts_rsi_info') + $this->unique_acct_count;

    $this->total_unique_records = $this->unique_acct_count + $this->unique_org_count;

    $account_refresh_range = $this->GetRefreshRange('accounts_rsi');
    //$this->account_refresh_time = $this->CalculateAvgRefreshTime($account_refresh_range);

    $org_refresh_range = $this->GetRefreshRange('organizations_rsi');
    //$this->org_refresh_time = $this->CalculateAvgRefreshTime($org_refresh_range);

   $this->total_refresh_time = $this->CalculateAvgRefreshTime(array(
       max($org_refresh_range[0], $account_refresh_range[0]),
       min($org_refresh_range[1], $account_refresh_range[1]),
       $org_refresh_range[2] + $account_refresh_range[2]));

    $this->current_refresh_cycle = 
        max($org_refresh_range[0], $account_refresh_range[0]) -
        min($org_refresh_range[1], $account_refresh_range[1]);

    $query = $this->DB->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(ip), SUM(times_seen) FROM api_users');
    $query->execute();
    list($this->total_users, $this->total_hits) = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}

public function GetSingleCount($query_string)
{
    $query = $this->DB->db->prepare($query_string);
    $query->execute();
    $unique_org_count = $query->fetch();
    return $unique_org_count[0];
}

public function GetRefreshRange($table)
{
    $margin = time() - (60*60*24*90);

    $query = $this->DB->db->prepare('
        SELECT 
            MAX(last_scrape_date), 
            MIN(last_scrape_date) 
        FROM 
            '.$table.' 
        WHERE 
            last_scrape_date > "0"
            AND last_scrape_success >= "'.$margin.'"');

    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch();

    $result[0] = intval($result[0]);
    $result[1] = intval($result[1]);

    if($result[0] == null)
        $result[0] = time();

    if($result[1] == null)
        $result[1] = time();

    return $result;
}

public function CalculateAvgRefreshTime($range)
{
    // Avg seconds per entry = 1 / ((max - min) / (count - 1))
    return (1 / (($range[0] - $range[1]) / ($range[2] - 1)));
}
}
```

It's saying this is the function with the error:

```
public function GetSingleCount($query_string)
{
    $query = $this->DB->db->prepare($query_string);
    $query->execute();
    $unique_org_count = $query->fetch();
    return $unique_org_count[0];
}
```

Specifically this line(59):

```
$query = $this->DB->db->prepare($query_string);
```

Comment: Then give the smallest amount of code that will reproduce the error.

Comment: What is `DBInterface`?

Comment: Should it just be `$this->DB->prepare($query_string);`? It seems odd for a database class to have a database property that you have to interact with directly.